# How to create a dynamic table from cs file

Tags: asp.net

I am fetching a data from sql.Result is like this.Country,State,City,Count.

```
India Maharashtra Mumbai 30
India MahaRashtra Pune 20
India Maharashtra Nashik 28
```

But I want to show like this in table.I am have created table from cs file.From table I am able to put into 30 in mumbai but entry for pune and nashik is going to next row.I applied logic here is if countryName is different put into next column.If state name is same,don't write more than once.In same row write for city count.But second country I am getting from second row of sql.

```
Country state Mumbai Pune Nashik
India 
       Maharashtra 30 20 28
```